# Putting telephoto lens on top of an OEM lens?

Tags: lens, optics, zoom, telephoto, camera

I want to use something like a [Wyze Cam v3](https://www.wyze.com/products/wyze-cam). Many users have removed the original lens and put on a telephoto lens. I dont want to remove the OEM lens. Can I put a telephoto lens on top of the original? Another user put a magnifier headset glass on top of the v3. So can I put a telephoto lens, magnifying lens or reading glasses? Basically, what can I do zoom?

Comment: What is a "magnifier headset glass"?

Answer (score 1):

Best if you remove the standard lens and replace with a telephoto. That being said, you can attach a small telescope so that the camera, with its lens, is looking through the telescope. You can buy a monocular (single half of a binocular) and affix it Infront of your camera. You can test this idea using a binocular you already own. Such a telescope mounted in this way is called an afocal mounting.

Comment: I don't own a binocular right now. Will get one. The reason I am doing this is I want to use wyze v3 as a peephole camera. My complex won't allow me to remove the peephole and no changes like door bells outside. I have tried with a smart phone and with zoom 2.0 it works pretty good. However the apps that provide motion sense don't like to use the newer zoom lens so that concept is out. Wyze would work but it needs to be zoomed. Most zooms are people removing original lens and replacing with telephoto. One person used headset magnifier to use v3 to view their 3printet. I don't want to ope...

Comment: ...open the wyze v3. Will putting monocular over the existing lenses help? What power should I be looking for? Can I use reading glasses or magnifying glass?

Comment: Sounds like an impossible task.  8X is standard, borrow a pair of binoculars and try this trick before you buy a monocular.

Comment: Will see who has one. When i did try with my smartphone on zoom if picked up outside the peephole because camera was bigger than the peephole. Any way to make the camera not consider the door space? Black tape or white taps or?

Comment: @GreenGiant it would be best if you edit your full scenario into your original question. It may be that someone has a better solution for you if you provide all the information up top.

Comment: @GreenGiant, Re, "I want to use wyze v3 as a peephole camera." Have you tried simply putting the camera up to the peephole? Generally speaking, if you have a camera with a normal-ish field of view, you can put it it's lens anywhere you could put your eye, and it will see pretty much the same as what you would see if you put your eye there.

Answer (score 0):

There are "filters" you could add the original lens.  My partner's Nikon D90 has both tele and wide angle "filters" that can go on the kit zoom; I've also got a 0.45x wide angle adapter that fits the filter rings on my RB67 lenses.

This will slightly affect image quality (extra glass surfaces not optimized for the existing lens formula), but in my experience not any more so than a tele-extender that goes behind the lens on an SLR.

These have the advantage of being relatively inexpensive; I got one for 77 mm thread for under USD50 -- that means, if you buy one and don't like the results, you aren't out a month's car payment (or rent) for an expensive full lens.