# Recreate this lens specification

Tags: lens, optics, diy, camera, optical-quality

So my Samsung note 10 details say this about their telephoto lens 12 MP, f/2.1, 52mm (telephoto), 1/3.6", 1.0µm, PDAF, OIS, 2x optical zoom. I tried using it to see through my peephole which has a fish eye lens. It works good. What is the best way to recreate this view using blink mini or wyze v3 cam without opening the camera. Would it work using readings glasses if so what strength? I have easy access to this. What about magnifiying glass, telephoto lens, or binoculars? Which one and what strength? Would prefer reading glasses because it easy found and cheap. Other options are harder to find but if they are better let me know. I am doing this because I rent so can't have doorbells or remove peephole for a peephole camera. Note 10 security camera apps don't use the nicer lens. So I have to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you suggesting putting reading glasses on the front of a security camera? This sounds like something from a Mr Bean episode.

Comment: How satisfied are you with the results you get by putting the security camera right up to the peephole, without adding anything else in between? If you don't have a security camera yet, can you borrow one from somebody?

Comment: Relevant: [Putting telephoto lens on top of an OEM lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/129705)

Comment: This issue has a long paper-trail being cross-posted  around the whole stack.

Comment: @Tetsujin I knew I'd seen it somewhere else! (home improvement)

Comment: I am suggesting putting reading glasses or anything that works to get this done. It's actually pretty good quality when I try with my smartphone. But the apps don't use the zoom lens. So it will be even better once I am able to use a zoom lens. I have tried posting on different stacks because it a security issue, a camera issue, photo issue and could be other places I can't think of. So help me figure this out thanks!

Comment: "the apps don't use the zoom lens" What _are_ you talking about? It's not clear to me. Why are you convinced you need a zoom lens? Reading glasses and zoom lenses have different functions. Did you read my second comment?